# Why is strtol() returning 0x7fffffff instead of the expected 0xAABBCCDD?

Tags: c, hex, long-integer, data-conversion, strtol

```cpp
// msvc 17.3.5
// sizeof (long) : 4
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    long i = 0xAABBCCDD;// 0x AABBCCDD in debugger window

    char number[] = "AABBCCDD EEFF";
    char* p;
    long var = strtol ( number, &p, 16 );// 0x 7FFF FFFF
    perror ( "?:" ); // ?:: Result too large
}
```

I tried `char number[] = "AABBCC EEFF";` and it works fine.
I expect `0xAABBCCDD` inside `var` instead `0x7fffffff`.
What is wrong?

Comment: "If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, a range error occurs (setting errno to ERANGE) and LONG_MAX, LONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX or LLONG_MIN is returned." https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol

Comment: The range of a 4-byte `long` is from -2147483648 to 2147483647.  `0xAABBCCDD` is 2864434397, which is outside that range.  If you declared `var` as `unsigned long` and changed `strtol` to `strtoul`, it would work as you expect.

Comment: @SteveSummit, it seems that 0xAABBCCDD in debugger window matching the long i variable didn't motivate me to check the range with sign. My mistake.

Comment: Always use unsigned types when working with hex and binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C Standard (7.22.1.4 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions)

> 8 The **strtol**, **strtoll**, **strtoul**, and **strtoull** functions
> return the converted value, if any. If no conversion could be
> performed, zero is returned. If the correct value is outside the range
> of representable values, **LONG_MIN**, **LONG_MAX**, **LLONG_MIN**,
> **LLONG_MAX**, **ULONG_MAX**, or **ULLONG_MAX** is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of
> the macro **ERANGE** is stored in **errno**.

The positive hexadecimal constant `0xAABBCCDD` can not be represented in an object of the signed type `long int` provided that `sizeof( long int )` is equal to `4`.

For example try this demonstration program

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%#X\n", LONG_MAX );
}
```

The program output is

```
0X7FFFFFFF
```

Note: as in this case `sizeof( long )` is equal to `sizeof( unsigned int )` and the value is representable in an object of the type `unsigned int` there is used the conversion specifier `X`. Otherwise you need to include header `<inttypes.h>` and to use a macro as for example `PRIX32`.

As you can see `LONG_MAX` (the maximum positive value that can be stored in an object of the type `long int`)  is less than the positive hexadecimal constant `0xAABBCCDD`.

Instead of using the function `strtol` use function `strtoul`

```
unsigned long var = strtoul ( number, &p, 16 );
```

Or if you want to deal with signed integers then use function `strtoll`.

Comment: `"%#X"`, Why `"%#X"` and not ``"%#lX"``?  Typo? Intentional?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica,flag for 'X' in output. https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @Squared Yes, but the point is it needs the `l` modifier (lowercase letter L, for **l**ong) also.

Comment: @Squared Yes, you may.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, "can we use "%#lX" sorry! I meant - what type of LONG_MAX itself? If it is a macros - then the will recognize by compiler automatically? So we cannot be sure, that LONG_MAX will fit into "%#X", yes?

Comment: @Squared <we cannot be sure, that LONG_MAX will fit into "%#X"> is correct.